# pys60 development by eric IDE

Tags: pys60, eric-ide

I want to develop pys60 by eric4 IDE. I know that it's so late and has no worth but I need it. The following link:

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/173353-Eric-Ide-perfect-IDE-for-Python-PyS60-developmant

describes it completely. I do all step. Step 7 and 8 is done by typing following codes in command line:

```
python C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\eric4\eric4-api.py -o C:\PyS60_api.api -R -p “C:\Program Files\PythonForS60\module-repo”
python C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\eric4\eric4-api.py -o python_api.api -R -p C:\Python27
python C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\eric4\eric4-api.py -o eric_pyqt.api -R -p C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

after this, “PyS60_api.api” file is created at “C:\” and “eric_pyqt.api”, “python_api.api” files are created at “C:\Windows\System32″. I add them to eric IDE by using ” Settings -> Preference-> editor ->APIs”, then compile and apply.

So I think that I had done all steps correctly. But I have a big problem. eric IDE does not know pys60 modules, for ex, appuifw, e32, camera, … . In other words, if I type

```
import camera
```

in eric IDE shell, then I have this error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
File “”, line 1, in
ImportError: No module named camera
```

I have Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using S60v3 FP1/FP2 SDK. Really it is the only way to develop and test PyS60 app on PC. You will need:

- Nokia S60v3 FP1/FP2 SDK
- Python 2.0.0 SDK (FP1 or FP2 accordingly) for Nokia
- OpenC 3.0 SDK plugin